# Emacs: Pymacs not loading ropemacs with Carbon Emacs

Tags: python, emacs, flymake, ropemacs, pymacs

I'm attempting to use Pymacs with rope/ropemacs for flymake syntax checking as described here:
http://www.enigmacurry.com/2009/01/21/autocompleteel-python-code-completion-in-emacs/

When I start Carbon Emacs "normally" it throws the error:

error: Pymacs loading ropemacs...failed

I had this working on OSX 10.5 with Carbon Emacs but it fails in 10.6. However, it works when loading "terminal" emacs, Aquamacs, or if I open Carbon Emacs from the command line using "/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs". I'm assuming this is some kind of path error, but I can't figure it out for the life of me.

My setup is OSX 10.6.2 and I'm using macports python 2.6.4.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are it is a path problem.  When you start an emacs from the terminal, your `PATH` environment variable presumably includes the MacPorts bin directory `/opt/local/bin` because presumably you modified one of your shell profiles, probably `.bash_profile`, to include that directory on `PATH`.

But when you launch an application directly (by double-clicking it) the shell is not involved so, by default, `/opt/local/bin` doesn't get included in the process's `PATH` variable.  Depending on how Pymacs, et al, invoke python, it most likely ends up with the Apple-supplied python2.6 (`python` or `/usr/bin/env python`).  If you can figure out where it's calling python, you could change that to an absolute path, like `/opt/local/bin/python2.6`.

If you can't figure out how to do that, you may be able to work around the problem by either modifying the plist file inside of the `Carbon Emacs.app` bundle to include a `LSEnvironment` key with the proper value for `PATH`.  Or you can create a user-wide environment definition for `PATH` in `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist`.  Both options are described [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPRuntimeConfig/Articles/EnvironmentVars.html).

Otherwise you could try installing Pymacs with the Apple-supplied Python 2.6.1.

By the way, the installation instructions in the link you cite use `easy_install`.  If you need to install packages into the MacPorts python, make sure you install and use an `easy_install` instance for it and not use the Apple-supplied one in `/usr/bin`:

```
$ sudo port install py26-setuptools
$ /opt/local/bin/easy_install-2.6 <package>
```